# GraphQL convention for querying by ID or path

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Assume you have a schema where a resource can be identified by its ID or a path (`/userName/projectName`):

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Project {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  owner: User!
}
```

To query a project, we need two resolvers:

```
findProjectByID(id: String!): Project!
findProjectByPath(userName: String!, projectName: String!): Project!
```

Ideally, we'd have just one resolver that accepts both kinds of identifiers:

```
findProject(???): Project!
```

These are the ideas I can come up with, but none of them seem very neat:

```
# Idea 1
findProject(idOrPath: String!): Project! 

# Idea 2
findProject(id: String, userName: String, projectName: String): Project! 

# Idea 3
findProject(identifier: ProjectIdentifier): Project!
union ProjectIdentifier = ProjectID | ProjectPath
type ProjectID { id: String! }
type ProjectPath { userName: String!, projectName: String! }
```

What would be the most GraphQL-y approach? Is there a convention that applies here?

Comment: To me it seems like multiple resolvers is pretty ideal, what's the benefit of overloading the resolver with multiple types?

Comment: It's not that using multiple resolvers doesn't work, but it leads to more bloat, particularly client-side because we have to multiplex between two different queries depending on which identifier we've received. I'm working with Typescript, so each query has its own type signature, and also Apollo hooks, so an if-statement isn't feasible either.